# Codeigniter controller properties between session

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I'm currently working on a codeigniter project and I've got myself all confused. In order to allow Ajax calls to come through to APIs without having to reference a `project_id` every single call, I keep the project_id in a session variable like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('control_panel_project_context', $project_id);
```

And simply retrieve it when the call comes through. I'd been using this for a while and then decided I'd try setting a property like `$this->project_id`

Which also worked when retrieving in an api function... But I don't get why. When the Ajax call comes through it's not going through the function which sets `$this->project_id` so surely the controller has no knowledge of its existence.

The only thing I can think of is that perhaps it's being set server wide. In which case, what happens when multiple people are making similar calls to the same function? Is it going to use the id of whichever project happened to be loaded by a user last? If it's behaving as I think it is, then I take it using a controller property is definitely not what I want and I should stick to session variables.

My understanding of server side properties is a little tricky for me coming from a front end background where every variable is that user's and that user's alone.

Comment: Where *does* `$this->project_id` get set?  What does your controller look like (can you provide a code sample)?  How are you setting `$this->project_id`, is it from the session variable?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry I just wrapped for the night so I can't copy any code, however, it get sets in the index of the controller which receives it as a parameter (uri) and then displays the view(s). I'm beginning to think that I made a mistake somewhere and that $this->project_id was never actually called and thus didn't really work. There's just no way it could.

Comment: Is it in the `index()` function or in the `__construct()` function?  The constructor is always called.

Comment: @RocketHazmat 100% in the index as I use the index to call all the pages with the project_id parameter being passed through.